# How to return a List in Apache Axis

Tags: java, list, jakarta-ee, arraylist, axis

On tomcat, I have a class that return a list of objects from the database, something like this:

```
List<Entity> list = null;
Connection con = null;
PreparedStatement pstm = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
try {
        con = Connector.getConexion();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM some_table LIMIT 10;";
        pstm = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = pstm.executeQuery();
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        EntityCrimesChicago ecc = null;

        while (rs.next()) {
            e = new Entity();
            e.setID(rs.getString(1));
            e.setCase_Number(rs.getString(2));
            list.add(e);
        }
        return list;
catch { ... }
finally { ... }
```

The entity and table have all fields as String/varchar, even the ID.

The service gets the list with (this is a web method):

```
public List<Entity> someThing(String q) {
    DAOThings controller = new DAOThings();
    List<Entity> things = controller.getSomeThings(Integer.parseInt(q));
    return things;
}
```

This return

```
java.io.IOException: No serializer found for class Entity in registry org.apache.axis.encoding.TypeMappingDelegate@26a0e5e4
```

But, If I change the web method to return a `String` and I use `return things.toString();` that return the objects, but doesn't the his content.

What can I do to return the list correctly?

I try returning a manueally added string list and works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem passing the object to a String array.

When I get the object list:

```
public List<Entity> someThing(String q) {
     DAOThings controller = new DAOThings();
     List<Entity> things = controller.getSomeThings(Integer.parseInt(q));
     return things;
}
```

I only need to do this:

```
public List<String[]> someThing(String q) {
    DAOThings controller = new DAOThings();
    List<Entity> things = controller.getSomeThings(Integer.parseInt(q));
    List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<>;

    for (Entity value : things) {
            String[] array = new String[obj_fields];
            array[0] = value.getAny();
            ...
            array[n] = value.getAny();
            list.add(array);
    }
    return list;
}
```

And Apache Axis does the magic.